# List connections to OS X Server, and what sharepoint they have mounted?

Tags: sharepoint, monitoring, mac-osx-server, file-server

I have an Xserve running OS X Server 10.4.11.  It has Apple File Protocol enabled to share a few dozen sharepoints on the local network.

I would occasionally like to get a listing of who is currently connected to the server (easily done with Server Admin), *but* I would like to know which sharepoints they have mounted on their local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Hah!  Good luck.

The AFP server gives precious little status information.  You can get the connections through Server Admin, but not the volumes that each user has mounted.

If you turn on the access log, you can see every single file Open/Close/Create going on, and from that you might be able to deduce what volumes people are using.  In fact, I have a script that monitors this log to give me ops/sec metrics on my AFP servers.  It's not an ideal solution.

You could also probably hook up Instruments.app or strace to see what the AFP server is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of connected users by running:

`serveradmin command afp:command = getConnectedUsers`

But that won't give you a list of shares users are connected to, just the users which are connected to something.